# Flutter geolocator checkDebugDuplicateClasses issue

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

I have a problem with adding the `geolocator (v 11.0.0)` Flutter package to my existing project. As soon as I add it to the pubspec.yaml file I get an error `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.`

To try and test if the problem is in my project specifically or the geolocator package, I created an empty new project (see below main.dart and pubspec.yaml code).

The new (empty) project runs (debugs) normally. But if I uncomment the `#geolocator: ^11.0.0` line in pubspec I get the beforementioned error.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Geolocator test"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text("Hello"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: geolocator_test
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  #geolocator: ^11.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

What am I doing wrong?

***environment**: Windows 11 Professional, Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1, Flutter 3.19.3, Dart SDK 3.3.1, debugging on  Pixel 7 API 31 virtual device.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Had this same issue. What worked for me was adding this to my android/app/build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency {
        if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
            useVersion("1.8.0")
        }
    }
}
```

}

> Just switch the useVersion("X.X.X") with whatever you need